# Javascript: Run a global function in the scope of a ajax response only

Tags: javascript, scope

I´d like to run a global defined js function in the scope of the return from a ajax request. I try to simplify my code, imagine a page with:

```
<div id="1" class="a">
```

and a function called on doc ready

```
function doStuff() {
    $('.a').each(...whatever..)
}
```

and an AJAX call on doc ready returning again an element

```
<div id="2" class="a">
```

In the case of success i´d like to run the function "doStuff", but i only want the element from the ajax response to be affected.
I expected that $.proxy would do the job but i don´t get it working (in the case of success from $.ajax):

```
success: function(data)
{
    var context = jQuery(data);
    $(jQuery.proxy(function() {
        doStuff();
    }, context));
}
```

But the element with id 1 is always affected, too.

Update:

The id´s are just for exsample. I do not have no valid unique id, that is why i want to narrow the scope. It loke setting the second context parameter globally (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) and no need to touch very js function using a selector..

If it is not possible, it would help me , too.

Answer (score 0):

It's affecting both the div's as you are selecting the element using the "class" selector.
you should be selecting the element using the id like below.

```
function doStuff() {
    $('#2').each(...whatever..)
}
```

This should work

Comment: I added those id´s just for better explanation. They don't exist, that is why i want to narrow the scope.

Comment: basically you have to identify the element which is unique, and there is nothing better than assigning them id to identify, and selecting the elements by class, is not effective or suggested either.

Comment: remeber, this is only a abstraction of the code. And it is a given criterium that i have no unique id. Otherwise it would be simple ;-)
And of course "not possible" is a valid result, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark new elements with a data attribute like `<div id="1" class="a" data-isNew="true">`, and tell the function to only to affect the ones with the desired attribute. For example:

```
function doStuff() {
    $('.a[isNew=true]').each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.removeData('isNew');
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: In this case the inital call of the function would fail. I updated the question to be more precise.

Comment: Yeah, for the above code, it will fail if you don't specify the 'unaffected' items with `isNew="true"`, like `<div id="1" class="a" data-isNew="true">`. You will need a way to tag new elements as such, so when the functions it will only affect the new elements only.

Comment: This would work, same like using id´s but it is not an option for me. It is a whole bunch of js i want to apply to the result and dont want to change all of them.